# .NET Core Entity Framework: updating C# code for existing database for tables and other objects

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use ASP.NET Core 6 and use Entity Framework with an existing database.

Since my database already exists, I need to do reverse engineer to generate the code based on the existing database. I have seen some tutorials which show how I can do it. But what I see is, I am only able to get the tables but not other objects like, stored procedure, views, functions or triggers.

I have two questions:

1. When working with the database first approach where the database already exists in EF Core, when reverse engineering do I have to generate code for the other objects like I mentioned above, stored procedures, views and other?
2. Is it optional or must I have them?
3. If they are required how can I generate them in C# code?

Comment: EF does only generate mappings for those objects it needs to access data. Other stored procedures can be called, but are not part of the OR mapping.

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) lets you reverse engineer a complete database, with all objects, into a Visual Studio project. You can then edit within the project and publish your updates to the database. But it has nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: So what happen in the situation if I make a change in table then I can run the migration script which would update underline database.   I thought I can generate a script from the EF/VS project that can run on any db for update purpose production db.  Now if I don't have Stored proc or views in C# code then update migration script would miss those objects and won't be good to apply to prod db.  Therefore what could be the best solution to have that done?.Maybe I can stick to create a manual db script or create a seperate db project in VS to generate the change db script for production dbs

Answer (score 1):

You can only generate models from existing database using this command -

DOTNET CLI:

```
dotnet ef DBContext scaffold "Server=.;Database=db_name;User Id=user_id;Password=password" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o  Models
```

PACKAGE MANAGER CONSOLE:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=db_name;Trusted_Connection=True;Id=user_id;Password=password" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

This command will reverse engineer db tables to models.

Comment: OKay I understood that I can migrate only tables into C# code by using reverse engineering technique.  What if I need to add a stored procedure or function. Would I have to define that in to C# code?  I seen some article where they are defining the sp in the project. I want to understand the situation when we are defining them in the code.  for example see this article   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/code-first-stored-procedure-entity-framework-6-0/.   Another thing is what if I want to produce the release script to apply on production how would I do that?